# Is it possible to make Nutch crawl a remote windows machine forlders?

Tags: nutch

I will break down the question :

1. Is it possible for Nutch to crawl folders/subfolders/files?
2. If yes, is it possible for Nutch to crawl a remote Windows folders?
3. If yes, how can we configure this?

Or Nutch is only for Web Crawling?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nutch can crawl files, if these files can be accessed via a browser.